# How to update Record with local storage adapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

for local storage adapter im using [LSA](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter) now i want to updata a model with id of 'ab12' in my model but i dont know how to dow it . my model is :

```
OlapApp.AxisModel = DS.Model.extend({
  uniqueName: DS.attr('string'),
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  hierarchyUniqueName: DS.attr('string'),
  type: DS.attr('string'),//row,column,filter
  isMeasure: DS.attr('boolean'),
  isActive:DS.attr('boolean'), //is added to one of type 
  orderId: DS.attr('number')
});
```

im my controller  im trying :

```
this.get('store').updateRecord('axisModel',{
   id:item.get('id'),
   orderId:index
});
```

but i get an error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'updateRecord'
```

i need to update orderId in model.and if im using commit() i get an error :

```
 updateSortOrder: function(indexes) {
        var store = this.get('store');
        this.get('getRowItem').forEach(function(item) {
            var index = indexes[item.get('id')];
            if($.isEmptyObject(indexes)) index=0;
            item.set('orderId', index);
            store.commit();
        }, this);
    },
```

the error is :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'commit'
```

and this is `getRowItem` :

```
getRowItem: function(controller, model) {
 return this.get('model').filterProperty('type', 'row');
}.property('model.@each.type'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DS.Model.save()`. In your controller:

```
var model = this.get('content');
model.setProperties({
   id:item.get('id'),
   orderId:index
});
model.save().then(function() {
  alert('saved');
}, function() {
  alert('not saved');
});
```

This is assuming that the `Route`'s model() method returned the instance, or you can use `find()` first:

```
this.get('store')
.find('axisModel', id)
.then(function(model) {
  model.save().then(...)
});
```

Comment: first thanks for your answer.i try your first way with model.setProperties() but i get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method save` and wen im using second way with using store i get this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method lookup of undefined ` at the second way in then method when i console.log model.get('uniqueName') i can see the correct name of record that finded. when im using DS.Model.save() nothing happend and nothing change in localStorage.

Comment: i think all this error happen because Local Storage Adapter dose not support last Ember data version